# How to run a batch file in specific day

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to run a simple batch file show one row message only, in the Valentine day 14-02-2014.

I need to write the day date (14-02-2014) inside the code, not do it as Task scheduler in windows. So, the batch will work every day with windows start up doing nothing, till that date it shows the message.

I just need the code for checking the date.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: what do you mean by 'show one row message only'? to echo a message to screen?

Comment: Yes, I just want to show "HI" message only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code run in a .bat file will get the date in a local-agnostic way (the output format of `%date%` can change depending on a user's settings), and then use substrings to set `today` in the format you want (dd-mm-yyyy). Then the `IF` statement checks to see if the date is today, and echos `Hello!` if it is.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "skip=1" %%x IN ('wmic os get localdatetime') DO IF NOT DEFINED dmy_date SET dmy_date=%%x
SET today=%dmy_date:~6,2%-%dmy_date:~4,2%-%dmy_date:~0,4%

IF %today% == 14-02-2014 ECHO Hello!
```

Comment: Thank you forxidrive, Jared Harley, sachadee, Chelesawillrecover for your time.

Answer (score 0):

:::For NT

```
echo off
set $Valentine=14-02-2014
set $TodayDate=%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,4%
if %$TodayDate%==%$Valentine% echo "Happy Valentine Day My Love"
```

:::For XP

```
echo off
set $Valentine=14-02-2014
set $TodayDate=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
if %$TodayDate%==%$Valentine% echo "Happy Valentine Day My Love"
```

Comment: The `%date%` variable is not reliable and is dependent on regional settings and location.  It's wise to use a function that returns a date string that is the same everywhere, like `Wmic` for `XP Pro` and above.

Comment: Effectively , your rigth but in 99.9 % of the case this code will be OK, and if not, easy to adapt :)